# Getters and Setters using returned data

Tags: java, oop, getter-setter

This may sound like a novice question but I'm still developing my knowledge around the core Java concepts.

I'll pose the question with an example.

Say I have these classes, a simple getter setter.

This first one represents a list of the second.

```
public class JobList {

private List<Job> jobs;

public List<Job> getJobs() {
    return jobs;
}

public void setJobs(List<Job> jobs) {
    this.jobs = jobs;
}
```

And then.

```
public class Job {

private String name;
private String url;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
```

In another class I have methods doing various things to return lists containing the values I want to in the getters and setters.

```
public List someMethod() {
//Loop through stuff to get a list of names
}
return nameList;
}
```

And say...

```
public List someOtherMethod() {
//Loop through stuff to get a list of urls
}
return urlist;
}
```

The information I get back in these two methods I want to be able to retrieve using the getters and setters for use elsewhere in the application. However I am unsure of how I can do this without putting getters and setters in the same class as the two mentioned methods.

Would I need to do that or is there another easier way/standard practice to do this?

Comment: what class contains the JobList instance?

Comment: On the class where those two methods are, you need to have an instance of `JobList` that you can reference in order to access its getters/setters.

Comment: @SteveL There's currently no instance of it created. From the other comment I take it this is required then, which does make sense.

Comment: @aribeiro That would be the case wouldn't it? Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
Set<String> collectNames(JobList jobList) {
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
    for(Job job : jobList.getJobs()) {
        names.add(job.getName());
    }
    return names;
}
```

This method collects all the unique (hence the Set instead of List) names from a JobList.

EDIT:

to use this method from a main method to print all job names do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JobList jobList = new jobList();
    // TODO: populate jobList with an array of Jobs
    Set<String> names = collectNames(jobList);
    // below implicitly AbstractCollection.toString() is called which returns a comma-separated representation of the contents
    System.out.println(names);
}
```

EDIT 2:

The method returns a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). You can iterate over a Set to get all its elements in turn:

```
// ...
Set<String> names = collectNames(jobList);
Iterator<String> it = names.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    String name = it.next();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: I've never used/encountered Set before so I wouldn't have thought of this. That said, this looks like a viable method.

If I were to do this and then say in a main method, run that particular method and then do a sysout on job.getName I would get back all the stored names that method processed?

Comment: no, see my update above. I suggest you read up a bit on Java basics before asking more questions here.

Comment: In regards to that update, would the contents be accessible one by one using something on the lines of: `System.out.println(names.get(i));` (of course using a loop or iterator etc)

Comment: no, see my update above. You cannot obtain items from a Set by index because a Set is unordered. I suggest you read up a bit on Java basics before asking more questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I second Adriaan's answer, but I would take advantage of Java 8 features, if possible:

```
Set<String> collectNames(JobList jobList) {
    return jobList.getJobs().stream()
           .map(Job::getName)
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```